# Data validation for text only in Excel

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

Please suggest me a custom data validation formula which allow text and space only

i.e. true for "John Smith" and "Monty" and false for "12356","45 Smith","John45", "John Smith 5", "78John" etc.

Comment: =istext(A1)         =not(isnontext(A1))    =not(isnumber(A1)   are not working.

Comment: try updating your question instead of posting comments with the update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
=ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH("~"&MID(A1,ROW(indirect("1:" &Len(A1))),1),"abcdefghijk lmnopqrstuvwxyz")))
```

Comment: You are excel master!